# sifr: Opera-Bug: Flash Object too wide

Tags: css, flash, sifr, opera

I have used sifr to replace the fonts for headlines. It works fine in Firefox and IE.

http://design.speak-friend.com/

In Opera however, the headlines of the articles (object-tag within a-tag with-in h1-tag) get as wide as the used text is. If I limit the size of the object-tag via css, it just get's cut off (meaning some text is not displayed at all).

Is there any solution to this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I used jQuery to increase the size of the embeds by some set number of pixels, like +40px. I guess you could also grow them linearly, like by 120%.

I'm curious to see how other people solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd! I'm going to assume that Flash doesn't suddenly behave differently, so the problem is in reading out the width of the HTML element. I supposed you could try limiting the width of the main element you're replacing to see if that helps. Or perhaps place the text in a `<span>` and replace that?